# Swing components resizing themselves when out of keyboard focus

Tags: java, swing

I am having two problems with the layout of my gui.
I am using a JTabbedPane to hold two JPanels, each panel has a selection of buttons and text areas, and each is laid out using GridBagLayout.
In one of my Panels I have a JScrollPane which uses a JTextArea. When I append anything to this text area and then click off the gui so it no longer has focus, or if I change the tab, the sizes of all the text fields and the text are changed to be as small as they can be.

To further illustrate my problem, here are before and after pictures of when i click off the gui after appending to the text area:
[image: Before I click off the gui]

[image: After I click off the gui]

Here is the code that I use to add the JTextArea to the Panel:

```
table = new JTextArea();
    table.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
    sp.setSize(40, 10);
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 4;
    c.gridy = 7;
    c.gridheight = 7;
    this.add(sp, c);
```

And here is the code I use to add the text Areas to the Panel:

```
title = new JTextField(10);
    author = new JTextField(10);
    dueDate = new JTextField(10);
    setDate = new JTextField(10);
    setWeighting = new JTextField(10);

    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    this.add(title, c);//add title field
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    this.add(author, c);//add author field
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 3;
    this.add(dueDate, c);//add dueDate field
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 4;
    this.add(setDate, c);//add setDate field
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 5;
    this.add(setWeighting, c);//add set Weighting field
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see some compilable and runnable code. Not the whole program, but just enough to reproduce the problem without being so big as to swamp us with a lot of unrelated code.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you set the weightx or weighty fields of the GridBagComponents. What happens if you set them to 1.0? If this doesn't help, again consider posting a compilable runnable small program that demonstrates the problem, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: It doesn't seem to change anything when I do that, the resizing behaviour still occurs.

Comment: Also, your gridx and gridy values should begin with 0, not with 1.

Comment: http://madbean.com/anim/totallygridbag/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to partially reproduce your problem like so:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo002 {

   private static final int ROWS = 5;

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JPanel assignmentsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      final JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(ROWS, 20);

      GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
      int insetGap = 2;
      c.insets = new Insets(insetGap, insetGap, insetGap, insetGap);
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      c.gridwidth = 1;
      c.gridheight = 1;
      c.weightx = 1.0;
      c.weighty = 1.0;
      String[] labels = { "title", "author", "date due", "date set",
            "set weighting" };
      int row = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
         JLabel label = new JLabel(labels[i], SwingConstants.CENTER);
         c.gridx = 0;
         c.gridy = i;
         assignmentsPanel.add(label, c);
         c.gridx = 1;
         JTextField textfield = new JTextField(10);
         assignmentsPanel.add(textfield, c);

         label.setPreferredSize(textfield.getPreferredSize());
         row++;
      }
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = row;
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      Action myAction = new AbstractAction("Fill Area") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
               sb.append("foo bar bif baz spam\n");
            }
            textarea.setText(sb.toString());
         }
      };
      assignmentsPanel.add(new JButton(myAction), c);
      c.gridx = 1;
      assignmentsPanel.add(new JButton("Button 2"), c);
      row++;

      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = row;
      c.gridwidth = 2;
      c.gridheight = ROWS;

      JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(textarea);

      assignmentsPanel.add(scrollpane, c);

      JTabbedPane tabbedPanel = new JTabbedPane();
      tabbedPanel.add("Assignments", assignmentsPanel);
      tabbedPanel.add("Modules", new JPanel());

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tabbedPanel, "Foo",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Before and after adding text to JTextArea, it looks like:
[image] [image]

And after clicking on tabs:
[image]

But it can be fixed by giving the JScrollPane a vertical scrollbar:

```
  // JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(textarea);
  JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(textarea,
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Which when run looks like:
[image]

Looks good on Mac OS, too:

[image]

Comment: Just tried that and the problem still occurs :/ thank you though :)

Comment: @lilroo: then prove it by posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) similar to what I've just posted above. This will let us see exactly what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to abstain from using Gridbag and use nested JPanels instead. I took the liberty of creating a short example:

```
public class LilrooPanel extends JPanel
{
    private static final int GAP = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame main = new JFrame("Dims");
        JTabbedPane tabbed = new JTabbedPane(); 
        JPanel myPanel = new LilrooPanel();
        tabbed.add("Assignments", myPanel);
        tabbed.add("Modules", new JPanel());
        main.setContentPane(tabbed);
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main.setSize(400, 400);
        main.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        main.setVisible(true);
    }

    public LilrooPanel(){
        super(new BorderLayout(0, GAP));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        Box north = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        north.add(new BorderPanel("Assignment Title", new JTextField()));
        north.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, GAP)));
        north.add(new BorderPanel("Author", new JTextField()));
        north.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, GAP)));
        north.add(new BorderPanel("Date Due", new JTextField()));
        north.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, GAP)));
        north.add(new BorderPanel("Date Set", new JTextField()));
        north.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, GAP)));
        north.add(new BorderPanel("Set Weighting", new JTextField()));
        north.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, GAP)));

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(new JButton("Add Assignment"));
        buttonsPanel.add(new JButton("Remove Assignment"));
        north.add(buttonsPanel);

        add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(new Object[][]{}, new Object[]{"ModTitle", "ModId", "Assignments"})));
    }

    private static class BorderPanel extends JPanel
    {
        private static final Dimension LABELS_WIDTH = new Dimension(100, 0);

        public BorderPanel(String label, JComponent right){
            super(new BorderLayout(GAP, 0));
            JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(label);
            jLabel.setPreferredSize(LABELS_WIDTH);
            add(jLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
            add(right);
        }
    }
}
```